# I am trying to create two stacked sections with different bxsliders in them. When second section called bxslider not working

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I am trying to create two different sections with bxsliders. Second section is hidden and it will only display once section2 clicked but When i try to clicking the second bxslider its not working.

```
<https://jsfiddle.net/dayan_z/6zjtnh6t/>
```

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this: [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/cmaaL2oj/33/)

**HTML**

```
<nav> <span id="s1">section1</span>
 <span id="s2">section2</span>

</nav>
<section id="section1" class="on">
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/666x375/000/fff.png&text=FIRST" />
        </li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/666x375/cab/fc1.png&text=SECOND" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
<section id="section2" class="off">
    <ul class="bxslider2">
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/666x375/666/375.png&text=THIRD" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/666x375/9a7/a1f.png&text=FOURTH" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/666x375/fff/000.png&text=LAST" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
    width:100%;
    background:rgba(240, 85, 36, 1);
}
span {
    font-family:sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding:1rem;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:.75rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
#section1 {
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    background:red;
}
#section2 {
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    background:blue;
}
.on {
    visibility: visible;
}
.off {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var bx1 = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        autoControls: true
    });


    var bx2 = $('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        autoControls: true
    });

    $('#s1').on('click', function () {
        $('#section1').toggleClass('on off');
    });

    $('#s2').on('click', function () {
        $('#section2').toggleClass('on off');
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:** [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/cmaaL2oj/20/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var bx1 = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        autoControls: true
    });


    var bx2 = $('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        autoControls: true
    });

    var off = 
    $('#s1').on('click', function () {
        if ($('#section1').hasClass('off')) {
            $('#section1, #section2').toggleClass('on off');
            bx2.destroySlider();
            bx1.reloadSlider({
                auto: true,
                autoControls: true
            });
        } else return false;
    });

    $('#s2').on('click', function () {
        if ($('#section2').hasClass('off')) {
            $('#section2, #section1').toggleClass('on off');
            bx1.destroySlider();
            bx2.reloadSlider({
                auto: true,
                autoControls: true
            });
        } else return false;
    });

});
```

**UPDATE**

The following is untested since I don't have a Mac yet, so *caveat emptor*

In referencing issues with Chrome Mac:

https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/issues/447

Try using jQuery 1.7 and if that doesn't work downgrade bxSlider as well:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.1.1/jquery.bxslider.js

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.1.1/jquery.bxslider.css

Comment: not actually what I am looking for but thank you. I don't think I am explaining it correctly, I will give it another try. I am trying to create a section that has two buttons. On default, section 1 will display bxslider 1 position top left corner. When you click section 2 button, section 1 will disappears and section 2 will appears in the same position displaying bxslider 2. If section 2 button is pressed when section 2 is displayed nothing will happen. If section 1 button is clicked then section 2 disappears and section 1 appears. I hope this makes more sense. Thank you

Comment: @dayanz My pleasure :) it looks like the 2nd slider is 20px offset from the top, but it's basically what you wanted. I think it's a bxSlider bug ... :\

Comment: Hello again. I have noticed when I click on "section2" the height becomes scrollable. It feels like all the stacked images are hidden below which allows you to scroll down. And then when you go back to "section1" it does the same. Could you help me out again. thx. https://jsfiddle.net/dayan_z/sjbLw9c7/1/

Comment: Are you experiencing this issue with what browser and what type of machine (mac, pc?)

Comment: browser - Chrome , machine - mac.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a Mac yet. I was hoping this problem occurred on a PC then I could go from there, sorry. It might be a bug: https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/issues/447 I've added some details in the answer.

Comment: is there a way to have content transition down from the top after every slide appears. [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/dayan_z/7dm6hvdp/)